# converting object of arrays to an array of objects in a desired format

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, arraylist, higher-order-functions

```
const getSelectedItemsIds = selectedItemsList => {
  let keys = Object.keys(selectedItemsList);
  let selectedItems = [];

  keys.map(k => {
    selectedItemsList[k].map(id => {
      if (k.includes("projectIds")) {
        return selectedItems.push({ type: "PROJECT", id });
      } else if (k.includes("subjectGroupIds")) {
        return selectedItems.push({
          type: "SUBJECT_GROUP",
          id
        });
      } else if (k.includes("subjectIds")) {
        return selectedItems.push({ type: "SUBJECT", id });
      }
    });
  });

  return selectedItems;
};
```

I have written my custom logic to get the desired result, if anyone can validate and tell me if there's a better way to do it.
I'm adding input and expected out below:

```
I/P: 
{
    projectIds: [2]
    subjectGroupIds: [] // incase multiple subjects are grouped togehter
    subjectIds: [4]
}

Expected format:
[{"type":"PROJECT","id":2},{"type":"SUBJECT","id":4}]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post this type of questions to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    let inputData = { projectIds: [2], subjectGroupIds: [], subjectIds: [4] };
    const selectedItems = this.getSelectedItemsIds(inputData);

    //Function Definition
    getSelectedItemsIds = selectedItemsList => {
        let selectedItems = [];
        let keys = Object.keys(selectedItemsList)
        for ( let k of Object.keys(selectedItemsList)){
          keys.forEach(key =>{
            if(key === k && selectedItemsList[k].length > 0){
              if(key === 'projectIds'){
                selectedItems.push({ type: "PROJECT", id: selectedItemsList[k][0]})
              }
              else if(key === 'subjectGroupIds'){
                selectedItems.push({ type: "SUBJECTGROUP", id: selectedItemsList[k][0]})
              }
              else if(key === 'subjectIds'){
                selectedItems.push({ type: "SUBJECT", id: selectedItemsList[k][0]})
              }
            }
          })
        }
        return selectedItems
      }

console.log(selectedItems) //[{type: "PROJECT", id: 2}, {type: "SUBJECT", id: 4}]
```